# Remove PHP extension without losing data post

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, post

This is my problem. I have this code to remove .php extension in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [NC,L]
```

But when my pages request an internal post request the data are lost.
I know that redirect do that but i don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Try adding the the `QSA` flag https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa

Comment: i tried QSA flag but not work!

Comment: You lose the POST data, because browsers follow a redirect that comes with a 301/302 status code, by making a GET request. 307/308 would be the correct status code to keep the request method. But you don’t normally externally rewrite POST requests, because the browser would have to send all the data again - so you’d effectively be doubling the traffic. And additional RewriteCond that checks the request method, and prevents the redirect if it was a POST, is the solution you’d usually go for in a case like this.